# find an ellipsoid given its intersection with axes and knowing the lengths of its principal axes

Tags: linear-algebra, conic-sections

My question is about ellipsoids.

I have an ellipsoid in 3D centered at zero so it has an equation:

$x^T U \Sigma^2 U^T x = 1$

I know the lengths of it's principal axes (therefore the $\Sigma$ matrix is known). Also I know three points of intersection of ellipsoid with x, y and z axes. How can I find the U matrix?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What I have reached so far. Because ellipsoid is zero centered it intersects axes simmetrically so there are 6 points of intersection which we know. Better than 3 but 3D ellipse requires at least 9 points to be defined. But we know three lengths of pricncipal axes. So how to put this together?